# How to read and compare the contents of files (check if the lenght of the strings the same)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I have a web application that allows me to upload files(text, code) and then saves them in a local folder.
What I'm trying to do is to read the files and then compare if the length of the files is the same and print out a report saying it is or it isn't. Down bellow is the code I am trying to implement but currently its not working.

```
const fileStorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: (req,file , cb) =>{
         cb(null,'./db');
     },
    filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
         cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});
const upload = multer({storage:fileStorageEngine});

application.post('/uploads', upload.array("file", 28), (req, res) => {
    let files = req.files;

    for (let file of files){
        files.shift();
    //    --------------------------
        function readFile(name){
            return new Promise(resolve =>{
                fs.readFile(name,function (err,data){

            } );
        });
        Promise.all(readFile(file),readFile(files).then(data =>{
            let file1 = data[0];
            let file2 = data[1];

        }));






    }

    // Send compare result
    res.send("Files successfully uploaded");


});

----------------------------------------------------------

let fileData = new FormData();
    const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");
    const btnUpload = document.getElementById("btnUpload");


    btnUpload.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (let file of inpFile.files) {
            fileData.append('file', file);
        }

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/uploads', {
            method: 'post',
            body: fileData,
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        //     Compare results




        }).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of promises, combine all promises to one promise and check the content:

```
application.post('/uploads', upload.array("file", 28), async (req, res) => {
    
    const promises = req.files.map(file => util.promisify(fs.readFile)(file.path));
    const result = await Promise.all(promises)
        .then(files => files[0].length === files[1].length);

    console.log(result);

    // Send compare result
    res.send("Files successfully uploaded");
});
```

Node.js also has promise API: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api

A working example with `util.promisify`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const req = {
    files: [{ path: 'a.txt' }, { path: 'b.txt' }]
};

(async () => {
    const promises = req.files.map(file => util.promisify(fs.readFile)(file.path));
    const result = await Promise.all(promises)
        .then(files => files[0].length === files[1].length);

    console.log(result);
})();
```

A working example with `fs/promises`:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

const req = {
    files: [{ path: 'a.txt' }, { path: 'b.txt' }]
};

(async () => {
    const promises = req.files.map(file => fs.readFile(file.path));
    const result = await Promise.all(promises)
        .then(files => files[0].length === files[1].length);

    console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: Im getting some sort of path argument error saying it has to be string or instance of buffer/url

Comment: @user15605539 What is `req.files`? As you can see in my code I'm expecting it to be an array of file name strings because of your code snippet: `fs.readFile(name,function (err,data){})`

Comment: its all the files I upload from the front end they are mainly text docs / hs/py/js/j

Comment: @user15605539 Why do you call `fs.readFile` with a file? If I correctly understand `files` already contains the buffer. So can skip the file read.

Comment: so I can remove `fs.readFile` but should i change the promise

Comment: @user15605539 If `req.files` is an array of files (content as string) you can simply compare `req.files[0] === req.files[1]`. You don't need a promise.

Comment: The application does upload and the console logs this https://ibb.co/pQQt0gg

Comment: @user15605539 The response doesn't help here. The question are: What is `upload`? Where does it come from and what does it do? What is `req.files`? Can you compare `req.files[0] === req.files[1]`?

Comment: The upload comes from my front end script where I have a post request and a form data. the req.files should be the array of the files that are uploaded to the folder

Comment: @user15605539 What exactly does the middleware `upload` do? What exact types do the elements of `req.files` have? Can you compare `req.files[0] === req.files[1]`? There are upload middlewares that store the uploaded files on the filesystem and pass an array of filenames and other middlewares that store the files in memory and pass the complete files.

Comment: I just edited the question and you can see the use of multer and the front end script Im using.

Comment: @user15605539 Yes, you updated the question but you haven't answered the questions: _"What exact types do the elements of `req.files` have?"_

Comment: the thing I am not sure is that if I use ``req.files[0] == req. files[1]`` would work because I don't think the application has read the contents of the files so it can compare them. My upload middleware currently just takes the files and uploads them to a certain folder.

Comment: @user15605539 Sorry, but I'm not going to repeat the same question for the fifth time.

Comment: `let files : any`

Comment: @user15605539 Do you really think that `let files : any` helps here? `req.files` can be an array of actual files or of filenames.

Comment: Well I am really struggling to answer the types of elements of req.files . The way I had it `let file of files ` was a way of taking the first file and then  `files.shift() ` was the way of changing the file so files is all the uploaded files. It is more likely to be the actually files that are uploaded.

Comment: @user15605539 Why would you call `fs.readFile(name,function (err,data){})` on an actual file? That doesn't make sense. You could find it out with your debugger or console.log debugging

Comment: I thought I need to read the file first so I can compare the contents

Comment: @user15605539 Have you tried `console.log(req.files)`? What is the output?

Comment: @user15605539 I updated my answer according to your image.

Comment: Im really sorry that most of my answers were stupid. Thank you very very much for helping!